# Creating SOAP message in Apache Camel when dataFormat is MESSAGE or CXF_MESSAGE

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-camel, cxf

I want to call a Web Service through Apache Camel and the dataFormat is MESSAGE. I want to construct the below SOAP message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope`enter code here`
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <platformMsgs:documentInfo
            xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <platformMsgs:nsId>WEBSERVICES_3479023</platformMsgs:nsId>
        </platformMsgs:documentInfo>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <addListResponse
            xmlns="">
            <platformMsgs:writeResponseList
                xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                <platformCore:status isSuccess="true"
                    xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"/>
                    <platformMsgs:writeResponse>
                        <platformCore:status isSuccess="false"
                            xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                            <platformCore:statusDetail type="ERROR">
                                <platformCore:code>DUP_ENTITY</platformCore:code>
                                <platformCore:message>This entity already exists.</platformCore:message>
                            </platformCore:statusDetail>
                        </platformCore:status>
                    </platformMsgs:writeResponse>
                </platformMsgs:writeResponseList>
            </addListResponse>`enter code here`
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can anyoneone help me with some code snippet or example which shows how to create this SOAP message?

Comment: Why "dataFormat is MESSAGE" for SOAP? Maybe POJO or PAYLOAD can be a better choice? Also with CXF Endpoint for SOAP there must be a WSDL and you do not need to worry about creating full SOAP by your self. CXF will take care of it. But if you still need to create full SOAP Envelope you can go with XQuery, XSLT, DOM builder... there are many choices, but all of them worse and slower that POJO with JAXB

Comment: Actually I have a WSDL that is too big to create POJO classes from it. For this reason I was unable to use dataFormat POJO. Also I need to add SOAP header but dataFormat PAYLOAD only deals with message body (most probably). So dataFormat MESSAGE is the only option. But using that dataFormat I am finding examples to read the incoming SOAP message but not create the SOAP message. Any examples in this area would be highly helpful.

Comment: You are going in wrong direction. Both your assumptions are incorrect. It is not a case "Big WSDL". You have to use it. Custom SOAP creation is a bad idea. With PAYLOAD ot POJO format you have your headers or you can create needed one. I still recommend POJO and focus on your actual functionality rether than spend yuor time to reinvent a weel.  All already is there: CXF, CAMEL,JAXB exactly to do what you need, correctly, fast, optimized.

Comment: Thanks Vadim, actually my WSDL will generate some 2000 classes if POJO is generated from it. So checking in all of them is a challenge. Can you kindly let me know or share some link about CXF_CAMEL_JAXB?

Comment: You are lucky :-) I have project with about 100K classes generated. There is nothing specific about CXF_CAMEL_JAXB. Right now I'm on phone... Later I"ll take a look and try to give you example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can provide you some idea about how to use CXF POJO format with Spring DSL.

Spring Context may look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<spring:beans xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel-cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
xmlns:camel-spring="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd       
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

<!-- inbound Service endpoint -->

<camel-cxf:cxfEndpoint id="my-test-endpoint"
    address="/myTest" serviceName="mySrv:MyService"
    serviceClass="com.foo.myservice.MyServicePortPortType"
    endpointName="mySrv:MyServicePortPort"
    wsdlURL="classpath:myTest.wsdl"
    xmlns:mySrv="http://foo.com/myService/">
    <camel-cxf:properties>
        <spring:entry key="dataFormat" value="POJO" />
        ...
    </camel-cxf:properties>
</camel-cxf:cxfEndpoint>
...
<camel-spring:camelContext id="MyTestService_Ctx">
...
<camel-spring:route id="myTest-route">
   <camel-spring:from uri="cxf:bean:my-test-endpoint"
            id="inbound-myTest-service" />
   ...
```

It is simple:

1. In Spring you define cxf endpoint as `{http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf}cxfEndpoint` bean,
2. then your reference to it from Camel route `from` or `to` components by uri which looks like: `uri="cxf:bean:{endpoint bean id}"`

Then You may have two cases:
Case 1. WSDL has Header defined as part of the message.  After service generated by Maven CXF plugin:

```
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
```

Just check how Service Interface looks like.

Case 2: WSDL does not have Custom Header defined and you need to add it.

for both look at my answer to another question:
[Unable to set SOAP Header while calling Web Service through Camel using dataFormat as POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284087/unable-to-set-soap-header-while-calling-web-service-through-camel-using-dataform)

P.S. if you do not need for some reasons, to explicitly marshal/unmarshal JAXB POJOs, you do not need anything else. You do not care about SOAP, etc. CXF will do it for you from your WSDL definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vadim!